# Google Closure JSON data submission with nested objects?

Tags: json, serialization, google-closure, google-closure-library, form-submit

I've been using Google Tools (library, templating) for almost a year... and I came to the point where a I have to connect the backend with all the templates i've been working on. The backend receives the data in JSON format.

Here's my problem. I want to submit a JSON that represents my object model in the backend and I know closure library offers this...

```
var json = goog.json.serialize(goog.dom.forms.getFormDataMap(form).toObject());
```

Problem is that the method **getFormDataMap** returns a **goog.structs.Map** which works like a hashMap... It means that all values of the form submitted are nested into arrays.

I was wondering if anyone has found a solution to this. I know that there is some library that does the trick like this one (https://github.com/maxatwork/form2js) but I can't believe that closure doesn't have anything to deal with this problem.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

why not access the data yourself and build the data structure you require, it is not like this will be a bottleneck of any sorts.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to do since I got tons of forms and complex data structures... Im searching for a way to automate it with closure tools...

Comment: I saw that plugin you were referencing, that looks pretty easy to implement imo

Comment: Yeah, this is what i'll use if I cant find any similar tools within closure tools !